# How do I express a Question mark (?) when searching with a space and text in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

Example

> That is so good isn't it?  Yes it is

I want to **find** a question mark that is followed by a **space** and an upper case letter. Then **replace** it with:

> That is so good isn't it?
>   Yes it is

I have tried various ways to no avail.

- FIND: `? ([A-Z])`
- REPLACE:  `?\r\r`

Comment: If you're using _Regular Expressions_, then `?` is a special character. So you'd have to escape it like `\?`.

Answer (score 3):

It's more efficient without capturing groups.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\?\h+\K(?=[A-Z])`
- Replace with: `\n`   # you can use `\r` or `\r\n` depending on the platform
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\?              # question mark, have to be escaped
\h+             # 1 or more horizontal spaces
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
(?=[A-Z])       # positive lookahead, make sure we have a capital after
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: "efficient" means "speed" when replacing all over a large search range?

Comment: @Yorik: Yes it's quicker because it uses less steps, you can try here: https://regex101.com/ with some text and different regex, it shows the number of steps used.

Comment: thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

try:

(enable "match case")

(find) `\? ([A-Z].*)`

(replace) `\? \n\1`

(note: `\` is used to escape special control characters)

`\?` : the literal string "?" followed by a space

`(` and `)` parens creates a *group* which can be referenced

`.` means any character and `.*` means any character zero or more times

`\1` is referencing the first group reference (the parens)

Comment: Your answer is what I have been looking for.  Appreciate your prompt response.  Thank you very much